# Can't run the touchlist project

Tags: android, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

I'd really like to implement in my app the touchlist widget, provided here:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist

So I downloaded it and I imported the project folder in Eclipse; I  tried to run as an ant build but I got this error:

```
Buildfile: C:\commonsguy-cwac-touchlist-af26192\build.xml

BUILD FAILED
C:\commonsguy-cwac-touchlist-af26192\build.xml:49: taskdef class com.android.ant.SetupTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Total time: 328 milliseconds
```

What's wrong with what I've done so far? It is driving me crazy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to right-click on your project and choose Properties.
On the dialog that opens choose Android from the left and in the Library section choose Add and add the cwac-touchlist project.

This is because cwac-touchlist was converted to an Android Library Project so you have to add it to your own project as a library.